# Need to fill in IP address of the Server in my Clients Connection EditText

Tags: android, sockets, ip

I have made my friends phone the SERVER and mine the CLIENT. NOW, to connect my phone to his phone, he tells me his IP address(eg. 192.234.34.12), I fill it into my EditText on my phone and then click connect. Our messenger works fine!
But, i dont want to have him Go into:

`SETTINGS>>ABOUT PHONE>> ETC ETC>> ETC ETC...`

I want it(his IP address) to appear in a TextView on his activity when he puts on our Messenger app.

For this i used a famous code i found:-

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); 
     en.hasMoreElements();) {

    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();
         enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {

        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
            return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

But it appears in IPv6, which is difficult to copy and it still doesn't connect!
But the moment I use IPv4(abc.def.xyz.lmn), it connects!

So my question is, how may I get my friends mobile ip(Server) to be displayed on his phone, so he may tell me it easily and i could connect from my Phone? may be in IPv4 if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is seperate class called [Inet4Address](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html)  in java.
Try this, it is working for me

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en =  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();                         
   en.hasMoreElements();) { 

  NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();
          enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();){

        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()&& InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress.getHostAddress()))
        { 
           return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); 
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Extract ipv4 address from enemuration object

Comment: ok great! This worked for me. i put your code in and got the format of IPv4, ie. xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa